# Request on php script with nsurlconnection

Tags: php, ios, xcode

i try to send value to server with this code by i have an error on this line:

`let reply = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error: &error)`

the error is : EXTRA ARGUMENT IN CALL "error"

```
var yourUrl="mylink"
let url = NSURL(string:yourUrl)
let cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: cachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 2.0)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

// set Content-Type in HTTP header
let boundaryConstant = "
V2ymHFg03esomerandomstuffhbqgZCaKO6jy";
let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundaryConstant
NSURLProtocol.setProperty(contentType, forKey: "Content-Type", inRequest: request)

// set data

var dataString = "my value"

let requestBodyData = (dataString as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData

var response: NSURLResponse? = nil
var error: NSError? = nil
let reply = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error: &error)

let results = NSString(data:reply!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)

if let dataFromString = results!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) {

let json = JSON(data: dataFromString)


if(json=="0"){

print("\n Dati non validi");

}

else{

print("\n Account creato");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never use sendSynchronousRequest as it is a blocking call. Also it is deprecated from iOS 9.0 onwards. Instead you can use NSURLSession. Try out following code

```
var yourUrl="mylink"
let URL = NSURL(string:yourUrl)
let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
let boundaryConstant = "V2ymHFg03esomerandomstuffhbqgZCaKO6jy";
let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundaryConstant
NSURLProtocol.setProperty(contentType, forKey: "Content-Type", inRequest: request)
var dataString = "my value"
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.HTTPBody = (dataString as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    //reponse recieved
    //in this case response string will be saved in data, its of type NSData
    do{
         let str = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]
         print(str)
    }
    catch {
         print("json error: \(error)")
    }
    })
task.resume()
```

Comment: ok thank you but when i print(response) i have this result:Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7f89185dc5b0> { URL: merl } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Length" = 0;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Fri, 05 Feb 2016 18:29:03 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
    Server = "Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)";
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.16";
} })
how i can print value of return?

Comment: Instead of response trying accessing value of `data`

Comment: thank i have another question: Xcode print: json error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}    my php code of link is:  <?php

    

      header("Content-Type: application/json");
    


    $email = $_POST["Email"];

    $password = $_POST["Password"];
    $ris="val"      return json_encode($ris);  because it doesn't print value of $ris